# How is the generator code works in a GAN?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, convolutional-neural-network

I am going throught GAN for image generation and I am using this [article](https://medium.com/towards-data-science/gan-by-example-using-keras-on-tensorflow-backend-1a6d515a60d0) for reference. The author is creating a generator model which does this. 
[image]

and the generator model code is

```
self.G = Sequential()
dropout = 0.4
depth = 64+64+64+64
dim = 7

# In: 100
# Out: dim x dim x depth
self.G.add(Dense(dim*dim*depth, input_dim=100))
self.G.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.9))
self.G.add(Activation('relu'))
self.G.add(Reshape((dim, dim, depth)))
self.G.add(Dropout(dropout))


# In: dim x dim x depth
# Out: 2*dim x 2*dim x depth/2
self.G.add(UpSampling2D())
self.G.add(Conv2DTranspose(int(depth/2), 5, padding='same'))
self.G.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.9))
self.G.add(Activation('relu'))
self.G.add(UpSampling2D())
self.G.add(Conv2DTranspose(int(depth/4), 5, padding='same'))
self.G.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.9))
self.G.add(Activation('relu'))
self.G.add(Conv2DTranspose(int(depth/8), 5, padding='same'))
self.G.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.9))
self.G.add(Activation('relu'))

# Out: 28 x 28 x 1 grayscale image [0.0,1.0] per pix
self.G.add(Conv2DTranspose(1, 5, padding='same'))
self.G.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
self.G.summary()
```

I understood most of the codes but I have doubts in these two functions

```
self.G.add(UpSampling2D())
self.G.add(Conv2DTranspose(int(depth/number), 5, padding='same'))
```

What is happeing in those layers?

Comment: The official documentation on [UpSampling2D](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/#upsampling2d) and [Conv2DTranspose](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/#conv2dtranspose) seems clear to me. What exactly is troubling you in these lines of code?

Answer (score 1):

You should either use UpSampling2D or Conv2DTranspose.

Upsampling2D just repeats the input. After Upsampling you should add a normal convolutional layer.

Conv2DTranspose is the backpropagated Conv2D, and there you do not neet any upsampling

For both cases read the documentary.
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.07285v1.pdf

Answer (score 1):

According to the official Keras MNIST autoencoder example here:

[keras/examples/mnist_denoising_autoencoder.py](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/mnist_denoising_autoencoder.py)

You use UpSampling2D along with Conv2DTranspose when `strides` < 2
They claim that it is better to use Conv2DTranspose with `strides` >= 2

```py
# Build the Decoder Model
latent_inputs = Input(shape=(latent_dim,), name='decoder_input')
x = Dense(shape[1] * shape[2] * shape[3])(latent_inputs)
x = Reshape((shape[1], shape[2], shape[3]))(x)

# Stack of Transposed Conv2D blocks
# Notes:
# 1) Use Batch Normalization before ReLU on deep networks
# 2) Use UpSampling2D as alternative to strides>1
# - faster but not as good as strides>1
for filters in layer_filters[::-1]:
    x = Conv2DTranspose(filters=filters,
                        kernel_size=kernel_size,
                        strides=2,
                        activation='relu',
                        padding='same')(x)

x = Conv2DTranspose(filters=1,
                    kernel_size=kernel_size,
                    padding='same')(x)

outputs = Activation('sigmoid', name='decoder_output')(x)

# Instantiate Decoder Model
decoder = Model(latent_inputs, outputs, name='decoder')
decoder.summary()
```